# Visual studio 2013 - Unable to resize Solution explorer / properties

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to resize solution explorer on the right hand side (tabbed with Team) - also Properties Window just under it. Usually, mouse pointer changes when hovering over an edge, but nothing seems to happen at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS gets funny sometimes, have you tried the good old "turn it off and on again" restart VS...?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "float" the solution explorer, resize it and dock it back.   That can resolve the issue.